# Compiling Python 2.7.10 with SSL support on OSX 10.11

Tags: python, macos, ssl

I'd like to be able to build Python 2.7.10 on OS X 10.11 with SSL support. Right now the `_ssl` module fails to build because Python is unable to detect openssl, which seems to be because Apple no longer includes OpenSSL in the 10.11 SDK. Apple's suggestion is for apps to use SecureTransport SSL, but as far as I can see Python doesn't support SecureTransport.

Is it no longer possible to build with OpenSSL support in an "out of the box" OSX installation, with only the XCode command line tools installed? I'd prefer not to have to resort to a package manager or to manage compiling my own version of OpenSSL. Apple has included OpenSSL as part of the base installation since at least OS X 10.5, so expecting it to be there isn't crazy I think.

Interestingly, Apple's own version of Python 2.7.10 has SSL support:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _ssl
>>> _ssl
<module '_ssl' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lin-dynload/_ssl.so'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you don't need to build OpenSSL, you just need the headers available and then compile Python against the headers.  Having openssl available provides other nice tools that may come in handy when troubleshooting SSL related issues.

Other than the doing the above manually (or using something like `brew`), there isn't a third way, as Python only supports openssl for its SSL support:

> This module provides access to Transport Layer Security (often known
>   as “Secure Sockets Layer”) encryption and peer authentication
>   facilities for network sockets, both client-side and server-side. This
>   module uses the OpenSSL library. It is available on all modern Unix
>   systems, Windows, Mac OS X, and probably additional platforms, as long
>   as OpenSSL is installed on that platform.

You should know that compiling OpenSSL on OSX has its own set of issues (listed in the [FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html)) - so it might be worth your while to stick to a package manager.

Comment: Thanks for the notion of "compiling OpenSSL on OSX has its own set of issues," it took me many hours before I gave up...